# Get the number out of references Table of contents

Tags: table-of-contents, bibliographies, natbib

This is how my table of contents look like in Latex code:

[image]
Where the section of Bibliography looks like:

[image]

[image]

But how do I remove the 7 in front of the references?

Comment: Section* might help.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `\section{References}` use `\section*{References}` which will produce an unnumbered sectional title. If you want it in the ToC then add the code `\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{References}` which will put **References** and the page number in the ToC.